# RegEx to get key and value from json

Tags: java, regex

I have a below json from that i have to get key and value

Below is my json

```
{
    "downloadImg": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
}
```

I want the outout as

```
downloadImg

data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

But I am getting stackoverflow error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3775)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
```

Why i am getting the stackoverflow error.Below is my code.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        clearJSON("{"+
    "\"downloadImg\":\"data:image/jpeg;base64,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\""+
 "}");
    }

    public static String clearJSON(String json) {

        Pattern clean = Pattern.compile(" \\s+ | ( \" (?: [^\"\\\\] | \\\\ . ) * \" ) ", Pattern.COMMENTS | Pattern.DOTALL);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher m = clean.matcher(json);
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
            // Don't put m.group(1) in the appendReplacement because if it happens to contain $1 or $2 you'll get an error.
            System.err.println(m.group(1));
            if (m.group(1) != null) {
                sb.append(m.group(1));
            }
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Please use a JSON parser to access your content, rather than a regex.

Comment: Any specific reason you're using a regex instead of converting the JSON String to a JSON Object? You could use `guava` or `org.json`

Comment: To add the start time and end time in the json request sent by client

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    clearJSON(
        "{" + "\"downloadImg\":\"data:image/jpeg;base64,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\""
            + "}");
}

public static void clearJSON(String json) {
    String[] tokens = json.split("\"");
    System.out.println(tokens[1]);
    System.out.println(tokens[3]);
}
```

Output

```
downloadImg
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```